# Python 2.7 64bit, Spyder 2.3.2 IDE and module pyzmq causes Spyder to crash

Tags: python-2.7, 64-bit, spyder

I decided to uninstall Python 2.7.8 64bit and all Python modules on Windows 7 64bit and have a fresh install of Python 2.7.9 with the new wheel modules from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

Procedure:

Uninstall Python with all existing Python modules.

Install Python 2.7.9 64bit on Windows 7 64bit. Install the following modules:
wheel, numpy, pyside, pyQt4, Spyder

I then successfully open Spyder. Under toolbar Help -> optional dependencies, I step-by-step i.e. checking Spyder works at each stage, install: ipython, matplotlib, pandas, pep8, pyflakes, pygments, pylint, rope, sphinx, pyzmq (which I think refers to zmq).

zmq is needed to run ipython within Spyder, which I want.

After I install pyzmq Spyder crashes.

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Please open a terminal (cmd.exe), run `spyder` (yes, in lower case), and then post the output here

Comment: Hi Carlos, spyder tries to run, then a window appears with spyder crashed during last session, try to reset spyder etc, then a window opens with python.exe has stopped working.

Comment: Ok, please now run this command `spyder --show-console`, so that it doesn't close the console where it was started.

Comment: What do you get when you type in a Python interpreter: `import sip` and then, if this loaded, `sip.getapi('QString')`

Comment: Carlos, Roberto, following the installation process described previously for Python34 64bit --- Spyder works normally! So I'm happy! However remains unresolved for Python27 64bit.